# How to install applications temporary into RAM on LiveCD?

Tags: filesystems, software-installation, system-installation, livecd, ram

So I have a Scientific Linux LiveDVD. And I have it installed on a PC that has no hard drives configured and avaliable at all. I want to install some applications that would allow me to configure system before I would be able to install OS.

So I wonder: how to create a temporary installation folder that would exist only while OS is running in RAM, install applications into it (using standart installer yum) and be able to run them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yum will do that by default in Live mode; anything you install whilst running off a live optical disc is installed to RAM because you are running off of RAM as it is.

If you want to do it explicitly, though, you can create a RAM disk:

```
mkdir foo
mount -t tmpfs -o size=4096M bar /foo
```

where:
`mount` is the command.
`-t tmpfs` specifies the type of filesystem. In this case, the filesystem type is tmpfs
`-o size=4096M` is for options and in this case, define the size as roughly 4gb. You can obviously make it larger or smaller depending on your needs and available RAM.
`bar` is the label of the filesystem that you are creating. Name it whatever you please; you'll rarely see it.
`/foo` is the location you want to mount the RAM disk.

I do not see an advantage to doing it this way; the live environment's default should work just as well.

Comment: But how to set yum to install apps into there and run apps from there?

Comment: Yum will do that by default in Live mode.